# Accent character in path of JSON functions in MS SQL Server cause error

Tags: json, sql-server, accent-sensitive

We keep some JSON's in our database as NVARCHAR. Before inserting, we validate JSON with "IsJSON" function. The problem is we have a JSON with Accent character in the keys like "Malārd". IsJson returns 1 which means it is a valid JSON but when we try to use it in a path such as '$.Malārd' it will cause below error:

```
-- QUERY
SELECT JSON_VALUE(N'{"Malārd":1000}', N'$.Malārd')
-- OUTPUT
-- JSON path is not properly formatted. Unexpected character 'ā' is found at position 5
```

If I have to, I will prevent inserting accent characters in keys, but I hope to find a better solution for that.

I know that I can replace accent character and use trick like COLLATE LATIN1_GENERAL_CS_AI but we have some infrastructure tools and API's in our project which allowed client developer insert and grabs a variety of JSON models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to surround [path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-path-expressions-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#PATH) expression with quotes if the key name starts with a dollar sign or contains special characters:

```
SELECT JSON_VALUE(N'{"Malārd":1000}', N'$."Malārd"')
```